# Efficient way to display upper triangular part of matrix as list in python

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity

Consider the following structure -

```
68 69 70 71 72 *
73 74 75 76 * 77
78 79 80 * 81 82
83 84 * 85 86 87 
88 * 89 90 91 92
* 93 94 95 96 97
```

I have to generate a list of the upper half i.e.

```
[68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 78, 79, 80, 83, 84, 88]
```

The structure is just for explanation, only two values are given, start and length, like in above case `start=68` and `length = 5`.

Here is my code to generate the list -

```
start = 68
length = 5

ls = []
for i in range(length):
    for j in range(length-i):
        ls.append(start)
        start = start+1
    start = start+i

print(ls)
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the inner loop, where you only append contiguous numbers. Replace it with one `extend`:

```
length = 5
start = 68

ls = []
for cnt in range(length):
    ls.extend(range(start+length*cnt, start+length*(cnt+1)-cnt))
```

Comment: It is much faster than my code. Works fine in my use case, but it is giving memory error for large lengths like 99999. It would be interesting to know how you will tackle that.

Comment: if `length = 99999`, you will be generating a list containing 5 billion integers. in practice, you probably wouldn't need to actually create this list at all. you might instead just write a function to determine whether a number `x`, for a given `start` and `length`, would be in the set.

Comment: @ShivendraSingh That's way too big a use case for this code. Consider distributed computing or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain

length = 5
start = 68
ls = list(chain.from_iterable(range(start+i*length,start+i*length+length-i) for i in range(length)))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel's answer is very clean and concise. Here is a more verbose version, which might help you understand why you can accomplish this with only one n-size loop:

```
def top_half(start, length):
  output = []
  # current length is the number of ints we want to grab from our current line 
  current_length = length 
  # current start is the int at the beginning of the line we are on
  current_start = start 
  for i in range(length):
    output = output + range(current_start, current_start+current_length)
    current_start = current_start + length
    current_length = current_length - 1
  return output
```

We can re-write this without storing variables for current_start and current_length:

```
def top_half(start, length):
  output = []
  for i in range(length):
    output = output + range(start + length * i, start + length * i + length - i)
  return output
```

EDIT: I'm not suggested you use this code! This answer is for illustrative purposes.